# 502 bad gateway from mollom captcha

Tags: response, captcha, http-error

My application uses Mollom captcha on some form-based pages. Suddenly, on one server, the mollom requests are taking excessively long time to return with an image and audio url's.
In the meantime, the server throws a 502 Bad Gateway or Network Error (TCP Error) in the browser. The issue lies in these lines:

```
MollomClient client = new MollomClient("PubKey1","PubKey2");
GetCaptchaResponse captcha = client.getImageCaptcha(null, null);
```

In the logs, I can see the response after 12-14 min, but thats of no use by then. And its happening only on 1 server (even there it was working fine till last week)

I rephrase. Is there a way to keep my jboss app server waiting for the response till it actually comes ?

Comment: That is an internet issue, nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this fixed by changing the public and private keys in my application. Looks like the mollom service was upgraded and no longer supports the older Client API